# Error getting the File download when Multiple User at same time and same file

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Getting the following error on file download by multiple users at the same time.

> The process cannot access the file 
>   'C:\ Document Repository\354\Calibration\ffc26999-4a5a-44df-9e00-fcaa3e70570c @ file_example_JPG_500kB.jpg_enc' because it is being used by another process.

How to resolve this issue in a C# MVC web application?

```
 public ActionResult GetDRFileDownload(long lng_DocRepositoryID = 0, long lng_OrganizationClinicFolderID = 0, long lng_DocRepositoryFolderID = 0, string flag = "", HttpPostedFileBase file = null)   /// We can use the over all project for download the documents /images
    {
        string DatabasePath = "";
        string filename = "";
        long _UserId = GetUserId();

        //  string folderName = "";
        string pathString = "";
        string pathFileName = pathString + "\\" + filename;
        string FileDownloadName = "";
        if (flag == "ClinicDocument")
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = serviceObj.GetResponse("api/JDocumentUpdate/RepDocumentDetails?lng_DocID=" + lng_OrganizationClinicFolderID);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var GetData = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DocumentClass>().Result;
            //var GetData = unitofwork.DRRepository.GetRepositoryFolderDocumentById(lng_OrganizationClinicFolderID);
            if (GetData == null || GetData.str_Path == null || GetData.str_Path == "")
                return Json(new { result = false, strMsg = "File not found" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            FileDownloadName = GetData.str_Name;
            DatabasePath = GetData.str_Path;

        }
        // var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Newpath + "_enc"));
       // UploadDocument obj = new UploadDocument();

        string DatabasePathEnc = DatabasePath + "_enc";
        string input = ""; string output = "";

        //string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(input1));

        input = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, DatabasePathEnc);
        output = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, DatabasePath); 

        FileInfo opath1 = new FileInfo(output);
        output = opath1.Directory + "/" + _UserId + opath1.Name;

        string Message = this.DecryptFile(input, output);// To decrypt the file
        output = opath1.Directory + "/" + _UserId + opath1.Name;
        opath1 = new FileInfo(output);

        if (opath1.Exists)
        {

            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(opath1.FullName);
            if (opath1.Extension == ".pdf")
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(output);
                return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
            }
            else if (opath1.Extension == ".png")
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(opath1.FullName);
                byte[] arr;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    arr = ms.ToArray();
                }
                img.Dispose();
                System.IO.File.Delete(output);
                return File(arr, "image/png");

            }
            else if (opath1.Extension == ".jpeg" || opath1.Extension == ".jpg_enc")
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(opath1.FullName);
                byte[] arr;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    arr = ms.ToArray();
                }
                img.Dispose();
                System.IO.File.Delete(output);
                return File(arr, "image/jpeg");

            }
            else if (opath1.Extension == ".jpg")
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(opath1.FullName);
                byte[] arr;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    arr = ms.ToArray();
                }

                img.Dispose();
                    System.IO.File.Delete(output);
                return File(arr, "image/jpg");

            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(output);
            }
            return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileDownloadName);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { result = false, strMsg = "File not found" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

This for Decrypt the File

```
 public string DecryptFile(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string s = "Success";
        try
        {

            string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                FileInfo opath1 = new FileInfo(inputFilePath);
                if (opath1.Exists)
                {
                    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            opath1 = new FileInfo(outputfilePath);
                            if (opath1.Exists)
                            {
                                opath1.Refresh();
                                opath1.Delete();

                            }
                            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                int data;
                                while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                {
                                    fsOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                                }
                                fsOutput.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

             s = e.Message;
        }

        return s;
    }
```

1. Get the File Name and Path from Database
2. Download the file based on the format

Comment: How exactly are you sending the file down? Multiple reads should be permitted on the same file. Please include some code to help drill down the issue.

Comment: Can you share your code? so every one see and give you answer otherwise your question will closed.

Comment: Sure I will add My Code

Comment: Why are you deleting the file? That would sort of make it impossible for two "simultaneous" downloads... Either it doesn't exist for the 2nd person, for the first person will fail on the delete...

Comment: We encrypt the File while uploading. So that we decrypt and store the file when got download request after downloading the file we delete the decrypted file

Comment: That does not explain why you are deleting the file being downloaded. It makes it impossible to download the file twice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now added the Decrypt code too. Kindly check it.

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma I have added the Code

Comment: Your problem lies in a combination of the file delete and how the output filename is built. Probably both instances get the same filepath from "the database". Build unique paths for the decryption that requires a delete.

Comment: You could also rewrite your decription to work on streams instead. No need to store in file on disk if it's just going to be read back up into memory again.